# Finding the pdf of $X_{(1)}$ of the two-parameter exponential distribution

Tags: self-study, density-function, order-statistics, exponential-distribution

I have to find the pdf of the smallest order statistic $X_{(1)}$ of two-parameter exponential distribution whose pdf is:

$f(x; \theta_1, \theta_2) = \frac{1}{\theta_2} \exp\{-\frac{x-\theta_1}{\theta_2}\}$ where $x > \theta_1, \theta_2 > 0, \theta_1 \in R$.

Here's my attempt so far: First, I find the cdf of $X_{(1)}$ using usual methods:

$F_{X_{(1)}}(t) = P(X_{(1)} \leq t) = 1- (1-F(t))^n$

Differentiating this pdf:

$f_{X_{(1)}}(t) = n (1-F(t))^{n-1}f(t)$.

Next, we find $F(t)$:

$F(t) = \int_{\theta_1}^{t}(f, \theta_1, \theta_2) dx = 1-\exp\{\frac{\theta_1-t}{\theta_2}\}$ (after a few integration-based calculations). Next, I plug this expression into $f(x; \theta_1, \theta_2)$ from before which (after some simplifications) gives:

$f(x; \theta_1, \theta_2) = \frac{n}{\theta^2}\exp\{\frac{n}{\theta^2}(\theta_1-t)\}$.

Now, I thought I was done here but, as it turns out, the worksheet I am reading *follows this up* with: "Denote $\theta_3 = \theta_2/n$. Then, $F_{X_{(1)}}(t) = 1-\exp\{-\frac{n}{\theta^2}(t-\theta_1)\}$."

**I have three questions**: Firstly, what's the point of finding $F_{X_{(1)}}(t)$ when an expression for the pdf was already found? Secondly, why is $\theta_3$ never used anywhere? Is this some kind of a typo? Lastly, where is $F_{X_{(1)}}(t) = 1-\exp\{-\frac{n}{\theta^2}(t-\theta_1)\}$ even coming from? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe start by finding the dist'n of the minimum of $n$ _one_-parameter exponential distributions with rate $\lambda=1/\theta_2.$ Then think about parameter $\theta_1.$ If none of $X_1, \dots, X_n$ can be smaller than $\theta_1,$ what about the minimum?

Comment: "where is $F_{X_{(1)}}(t)=\cdots$ even coming from?" - You found $F_{X_{(1)}}(t)=1-(1-F(t))^n$ right? So plug that in. You get the cdf directly and not through pdf. And one reason to prefer cdf is that it is uniquely defined, so there is no chance of ambiguity.

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3680094/321264.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to do the derivation for you, but here are comments, some of which may be helpful.

I think an approach using the CDF may be useful from the start.
Let $V = X_{(1)}.$
$$1 - F_V(v) = P(V > v)= P(X_1 > v, \dots, X_n > v) = [P(X_i < v)]^n \cdots.$$

I'm not sure if it's a difficulty for you, but sometimes differentiation methods can be puzzling if the support of the distribution depends on one of the parameters.
Also, you seem to be mixing up $\theta_2$ and $\theta^2.$

If you ignore the shift parameter
as you begin, I hope you can use the CDF method to show that
the minimum $X_{(1)}$ of $n$ is again exponential with $n$ times
the original rate.

Maybe the following simulation in R will give you some further hints. The program simulates $B=100\,000$ samples of size $n = 10$ and finds the minimum of each. The histogram of $B$ minimums at the end imitates the distribution of $V=X_{(1)}.$ [In R, exponential distributions are parameterized in terms of rate $\lambda = 1/\theta,$ where $\theta$ is the scale; so I am using $\lambda.]$

```
set.seed(517)
shift = 5;  lam = 1/20;  n = 10
min = replicate(10^6, min(rexp(10, lam)+shift))
summary(min)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  5.000   5.575   6.385   7.000   7.772  35.728 

hist(min, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2", main="")
 curve(dexp(x - shift, 10*lam), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]